# Как сделать перетягивание и увеличение изображения как в примере?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, drag-n-drop

https://www.mapplic.com/real-estate/?location=lot28
Здесь реализован функционал наподобии карты, меня интересует есть ли либы jquery которые позволяют перетягивать изображение и увеличивать как в примере.

prntscr.com/h2zjn4 у меня почему-то пример перестал открываться я добавил скрин. На скрине не видно, но зажал ЛКМ можно перетягивать карту в этом фиксированном окне

Answer (score 0):

Из готовых решений: map builder как раз подходит под ваш пример: SVG элементы, масштаб, scroll/drag [MapSVG](http://mapsvg.com/jquery/)

Либо можно воспользоваться [Draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/) модулем у jQuery UI, настроить как надо, повесить события и т.д.

UPD: 
изменить размер пикчи при скролле можно, повесив `mousewheel` ивент и изменяя в нём `transform: scale(1.0)`, предварительно задав `display: block`

UPD2: вот пример реализации scale on scroll

```js
$('.map-box>.map').each((i, el) => {
  let map = $(el)
  if (map.hasClass('is-scallable')) {
    map.mousewheel(e => {
      e.preventDefault()
      let matrix = map.css('transform')
        .substr(7)
        .replace(')', '')
        .split(',')
      let scale = +matrix[0] + e.deltaY * 0.1
      console.log(scale, e.deltaY)
      map.css('transform', 'translate(-50%, -50%) scale(' + Math.min(Math.max(scale, 1), 10) + ')')
      return false
    })
  }
})
```

```css
.map-box {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden
}

.map {
  display: block;
  background: #ddd;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  object-fit: cover
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.13/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>

<div class="map-box">
  <img class="map is-scallable" src="https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/uTZe8tzx07sI0i61YBPbkFupFHY=/0x90:1024x773/1200x800/filters:focal(0x90:1024x773)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/assets/990141/old-map-england.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: а, где возможность двигать мышкой картинку? в примере это есть

Comment: @Air возможность двигать мышкой картинку есть по ссылочке на Draggable модуль для jQuery UI. Пихать всё в один "пример" и полностью реализовывать его под нужды "спрашивающего" смысла не вижу. Для такого есть фриланс площадки

Comment: если честно, согласен с тобой, вот в данный момент, я бы вопрос удалил(но у меня нет таких прав), потому, что субъект который задает вопрос, он не пытается учиться и обмениваться опытом, а просто думает, что тут бесплатный фриланс, желательно не отвечать на вопросы такого рода... я считаю,  что это неуважение к коллегам...

Comment: @Air только вот одно но. "Субъект" сверху не просил написать за него проект, а лишь хотел узнать какие существуют либы для jQuery. А вот вопрос по реализации я уже увидел от вас, молодой человек

Comment: Какой вопрос?   Screaming Voices, дело в том, что задавать  правильно, хорошо для всех, когда ты завтра будешь, что-то искать, точно найдешь, тебе надо было просто привести пример того, что ты сделал и что у тебя не получилось и как  и что ты пытался реализовать...  надеюсь "субъект" тебя не оскорбил))

Comment: я в JS не опытен, что-то могу, что-то нет... учусь...  и хорошо для всех когда есть пример с ошибками и пример с правильным ответом... это развивает

Comment: @Air , я конечно дико извиняюсь, но я не просил сделать за меня работу, для этого есть определённые сервисы. Я просто спросил есть ли что-то у кого на примете и не потому что меня в гугле забанили а лишь по той причине что сообщество знает больше личности. А Вас видимо просто кто-то обидел.

Comment: @ScreamingVoices спасибо большое, ответ очень развёрнутый.

Comment: Николай, не знаю с чего у тебя сложилось мнение, что меня кто-то обидел, не понял, что ты там о гуглу написали, кто и как тебя там забанил. почитай будет полезно https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help